# Why only home directory?

Tags: home-directory, external-hdd, hard-drive

I want to save my Ubuntu-One folder in my secondary HD, just like my Dropbox folder. I know that saving data in a secondary disk is "the old way", but i bring this habit from my kid days using windows. Is it going to be always this way, or will I be able to share other folders outside /home in the future??

Comment: You could always just store /home in a separate partition... did you ever do this?

Comment: why not symlink a folder inside home to that external hd?

Comment: That might be dangerous, as I've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason might be that it's more difficult to sync files on removable devices. How should Ubuntu One react when you disconnect the device? If you remove a file, then Ubuntu One will delete it from all your devices and from your online storage. This could be overcome for removable devices, of course, but it is a special case and I don't think it has high priority.

I don't know how Ubuntu One decides not to sync files outside your home directory. It may be possible to mount the partition in your home. But it is also possible that if you unmount it, Ubuntu One will delete those files from synced devices. So be cautious if you try this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying makes sense. But I was not talking about removable devices. In this particular case is an internal SATA HDD that I use to store only data.

I do not know if it does make any difference if it is removable or not because it need to be mounted anyway.

The thing is that I have my dropbox directory in that device and it syncs perfectly.
Maybe because dropbox syncs only with the dropbox directory, and you can sync as many directories as you want with Ubuntu One (always inside /~). It seem like two different approaches. But at the end is the same, with dropbox you only sync what is inside of /dropbox, with Ubuntu One you only sync what is inside of /home.

I will take a look further in time, either when I change my storing philosophy or if Ubuntu One changes theirs. The first one feels more probable.

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: That should have been a comment, not an answer. But you do know that you can mount a disk inside your home? For instance mount /dev/sdb1 in /home/andres/Music? I don't know if that would cause it to sync, but it might be worth a try. Or just create a symlink, maybe.